# How to tile in left-right-bottom-top order in imagemagick montage

Tags: imagemagick, montage

I have a several sets of numbered png images *(mostly 00-23 but some are different lengths)* that I am trying to combine in imagemagick montage, but I need to have them tiled in left-right-bottom-top instead of left-right-top-bottom order. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "-scene" command to specify the "tile number". 
[Check out the imagemagick documentation here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?ImageMagick=79b8555hj16psjvtn06thhqp00#scene).