# How to set the order of a ImageMagick montage

Tags: php, windows, cmd, imagemagick

I want to order images not in the natural order (left-right-top-bottom) but in the order top-bottom-left-right. So when i have 8 images i want to have the first 4 in the first column and the images 5-8 in the second column.

```
1 5
2 6
3 7
4 8
```

But as in the [montage usage guide](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/#tile) i get:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
```

I'm using `montage -mode concatenate -tile 2x4 input_*.png output.png`

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695597/how-to-tile-in-left-right-bottom-top-order-in-imagemagick-montage), but the answer to use `-scene` doesn't affect the result.

Another way would be to do it in two steps, so first create just the rows with `montage -mode concatenate -tile 1x{nrOfRows} input_*.png output.png` and after that create the columns with the output of the previous command with `montage -mode concatenate -tile {nrOfColumns}x1 output*.png result.png`.

The problem is that currently i have 1024 images and want them in 64x16 and so the output.png's become `output_0.png` to `output_63.png`. So when i run the second command the order is:

```
output_0.png
output_1.png
output_10.png
...
output_19.png
output_2.png
output_20.png
....
```

and so some rows are not correct.

Every hint is appreciated!

(Currently i test this via the cmd on a Windows machine but later want to have it in PHP on Linux machine)

Comment: Do you have PHP on Windows so you only have to do it once? Also, do you use any other options in (like frames, borders, spacings) in your `montage` command, or is it just `montage -tile axb file*.png result.png`

Comment: I only use the option -background none. Imagick is already set up in the Linux environment.

Comment: Do you have PHP on Windows?

Comment: Are the files created by you, or something you control? Could you zero-pad their numbers out to 4 digits - `output_0001.png`, `output_0002.png` so they collate in order.

Comment: I have also PHP on Windows. And the output files are created by Imagemagick.

Comment: Where you create the files using ImageMagick, try using `output_%04d.png` to zero-pad the filenames.

Comment: This one works for me...
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To summarize:

```bash
rows=10
columns=20
```

- concatenate images in a `left to right, top to bottom` order:

  ```bash
  montage -mode concatenate -tile ${columns}x${rows} input*.jpg output.jpg
  ```
- concatenate images in a `top to bottom, left to right` order:

  ```bash
  montage -mode concatenate -tile 1x${rows} input*.jpg _tmp_%04d.jpg
  montage -mode concatenate -tile ${columns}x1 _tmp_*.jpg output.jpg
  rm _tmp_*.jpg
  ```